# Can Siri Shortcuts handle dynamic phrases and variables

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, siri, sirikit

i want to know is it possible for user to say

"balance in ***all cards***" or "balance in ***home***" or "balance in ***work***"

how can user acheave this with one sentence

now user has to invoke siri siri with static phrase like "show my balance"  then it askes for which card? then user ansers that to get the value
is it possible to do it with one sentense like:

"Balance of </Home/> card in cashAPP"

this way it introduce a whole new possible way of entering data with siri
imagine you could say :

"new expense in home category with 20 dollar"
is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not yet possible although the system shows promise for this feature.